# IE is not displaying text updated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In my project I developing a web interface for the device. The device's time and name is updated on webpage using AJAX.

On first run, when a webpage is created(updated) the page is properly displayed by IE8 but on refresh/revisit, the time is displayed properly but device name text(which changes occasionaly) is absent. I am using innerHTML property to update the text.

I do not face this problem when I access pages on Google Chrome. I have also disabled cache using HTML header. The HTML header is as given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

script:

```
function OnComplete (xmlDoc)    {
    /* ToDo: Add complete event here or remove method
           xmlDoc contains the received XML Document */
    try{                                    
        var txt=""; 
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DateTime"); 
        document.getElementById("idClock").innerHTML = x[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TCOLOR"); 
        document.getElementById("idClock").style.color = x[0].firstChild.nodeValue;             
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("deviceNameType"); 
        alert(x[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHTML = x[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ALARM"); 
        var alarmImg = document.getElementById("idImgAlarm"); 
        var value = x[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
        switch(value){ 
            case '0': 
                SetClassName( alarmImg, 'replace', 'hidden', 'inline' ); 
                break; 
            case '1': 
                alarmImg.src = 'Alarm.gif'; 
                SetClassName( alarmImg, 'replace', 'inline', 'hidden' );  
                break; 
            case '2': 
                alarmImg.src = 'Alarm_static.jpg'; 
                alarmImg.className ="p4 pr10 f_r pointer inline"; 
                break; 
            default: 
                alert("default"); 
                break;
        } 
    }catch(e){/*alert('ERROR\n'+ e);*/}
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><rtc><DateTime>2010-12-03 13:01:39 (UTC)</DateTime><TCOLOR>#0</TCOLOR><deviceNameType>AA1J1Q01A1, MYDEVICE</deviceNameType><ALARM>1</ALARM></rtc>
```

The alert() works with chrome but not IE.

How can I fix this problem in Internet Exploer 8?

Comment: HTML header if not displayed properly:

Comment: The doctype likely has nothing to do with it. Please provide the JavaScript code you are using.

Comment: @Dhaval, I fixed it for you - you need to highlight the "code" in your question and click the Code button (with 0s and 1s on it). Or, indent each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: From where you get the that text?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery at all (i know you said JS) try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX get requests are cached in IE.  You need to set cache to false: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

benhowdle89's solution affects the global ajax settings, so any ajax request on the page will not cache results.